# How to remove truncate part of url from azure application gateway rewrite url

Tags: api-gateway

I wanted to truncate part of url from incoming request to azure application gateway. We have single page application hosted in azure storage account and in front of it application gateway is there.

incoming request is //abc.com/**sit1/index.html** --> I need to route to //**/index.html**
I want to remove sit1 from incoming request and route to destination as only /index.html

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the desired outcome can be obtained by creating a rewrite rule like the following:

[image]

Here is the result:

Incoming request to the App Gateway:

[image]

Routing result:

[image]

PS: The configuration above will maintain everything in the URL path after "/sit1", removing just the "/sit1" part. The rule can be made more restrictive if needed (e.g.: replacing the pattern to match with /sit1/index.html and the URL path value with /index.html, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for similar solution for MVC application. In SPA application it is easy to handle. If angular, Just mention basehref="/site1/" in index.html. angular will works fine with that url part.